# Azure function running with a python version different than the VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I'm trying to debug my azure function, with python, in visual studio code. However, when I press F5, I continue to have this problem: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091.

So I noticed that I got this errors on the terminal:

1- cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'.

2- Also, when I press F5, I noticed that my azure function is using python version 3.7.2, but my IDE is using python version 3.9.2

Can someone help me solve this problem please?

Comment: can you get the version of grcpio with `pip show grpcio` ?

Comment: also you can change the python interpreter version in VS Code when you click on python version in bottom left  corner and choose the right version from the promt window.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I got version:1.23.0

Comment: can you also check pip version with `pip --version` to make sure you use same python interpreter

Comment: I got version:21.0.1

Comment: and which python version is pip using?

Comment: python  version 3.9.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230310/discussion-between-sofia-and-bijay-regmi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cyrgrpc` is the module containing the gRPC C extension -- native code that must compile against the API and ABI of a specific Python interpreter version. This seems to come down in a mismatch between the Python version of your package manager (whether it's pip or poetry or something else) and the runtime interpreter being used by your IDE.

Take a look at the installable `grpcio` wheels [here](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/1.36.1/#files). All except the source distributions (which you probably don't want) include a substring of the filename indicating which version of CPython it was compiled against. For example, `grpcio-1.36.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` is a Python 3.9 wheel.

You haven't supplied the particulars of how the package was installed or the relationship between your IDE's runtime interpreter and your package manager, so I can't help you much there. But you need to ensure that the versions match between the two.